# Зачем нужны "магические" геттеры и сеттеры?

Tags: php

Добрый день!

Хотелось бы понять, зачем нужны "магические" `__get()`, `__set()` и `__call()`. Ведь они срабатывают только при попытке получить данные из несуществующего свойства (на примере `__get()`). Получается, что их область применения - "отлов" несуществующих свойств и методов? И все?

Заранее извиняюсь за свою некомпетентность...

Comment: Иногда может так случиться, что Вы не знаете, какие свойства будут у Вашего объекта. Например, если этот объект - конфиг или json/xml объект.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вся "магия" данных методов сводится к тому, что они могут перехватывать (отсюда их второе название - методы-перехватчики) сообщения, посланные неопределенным (по сути - несуществующим) методам и свойствам.

Подробней прочитать можете [тут](http://codeharmony.ru/materials/192) или [тут](https://habrahabr.ru/post/197332/)